# What makes the listview get another item when updating

Tags: c#

The program I am making stores coins in an Access database. The project uses `WinForms` and has a `ListView` and some textboxes and 2 buttons: Add and save/update.

Now I have the adding records in real time working.  But the update is another story.

When I make the changes then click the save/update button it will add another row to the `ListView` and in the database it updates that entry, BUT it does not create a second entry as it appears when it adds that second entry to the `ListView`.

This is the code I have for the save button.

this is the method I call.

```
private void UpdateData()
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from coins", connection);
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow myRows in dt.Rows)
            {

                listView1.Items.Add(myRows[1].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRows[2].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRows[3].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRows[4].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRows[5].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRows[7].ToString());
                listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(myRows[0].ToString());

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```

and this is the code for the button which in this code you will see I call this `updatedata` method

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;
            string query = "UPDATE coins set c_qty ='" + txtQty.Text + "',c_year = '" + txtYear.Text + "',c_mint = '" + cmbMint.Text + "',c_grade = '" + cmbGrade.Text + "',c_type = '" + cmbType.Text + "',c_notes = '" + txtNotes.Text + "' WHERE id =" + txtID.Text + "";
            command.CommandText = query;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Data Edit Saved !");

           connection.Close();
           UpdateData();
                    }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error " + ex);
        }
        LoadData();
    }
}
```

What I did try was I edited the code in the `updatedata` method and was able to get it not to add to the `ListView` and it still did update in the database but the GOAL is to update the entry in real time by reloading or refreshing the `ListView` once the save/update button is clicked.

Comment: You question is confusing, particularly this part:  " However it does update in the database, but it done create the 2nd entry which is good."  Can you please clarify what you mean here?

Comment: I will try and Sorry for the typo. Basically what I am saying that when I make the changes then click the save/update button it will add another row to the listview BUT in the database it updates that entry but does not create a second entry as it appears when it adds that 2nd entry to the listview.

Comment: I think it will also help if you give us an example of a row you edit, and what happens in the ListView and what happens in the database, versus what you expect to happen.  You can edit your question and add the example.

Comment: I was able to get it to NOT to add in the new entry on the list view by commenting out this line of code in the UpdateData -  //da.Fill(dt); So now I just need to get it to show the changes without me restarting the program
Are we allows to add in images?

Comment: You can add links to images.